# Stripe When to use \Stripe\InvoiceItem::create and Charge::create?

Tags: stripe-payments

Good day! I'm new to stripe and I want to ask when to use

> \Stripe\InvoiceItem::create and Charge::create?

I read stripe documentation but I'm still confused when or in what situation should I use

> \Stripe\InvoiceItem::create
>
> Charge::create

Hope someone can explain it me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do only one time payment then you surely use **Stripe charge**, but the case is where you have to do recurring payment,So go with subscriptions.
In recurring you have to create products, plans, customers and finally subscribe them to your plan.After that you can send Invoice, createInvoice.
If any problem lmk
ref : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart